# CSS dot leaders at first line over complex background

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to implement dot leaders after first line of text using CSS to use it over texture/image background.

Expected behaviour:

[image]

I saw a few implementation of dot leaders over the internet. They all use one of the techniques below:

1. ::after dots + overflow

```
<div class=item1>
  <span class=text1>
    Text
  </span>
  <span class=price1>
    $100
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.item1 {
  display: flex;
}
.text1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
  width: 100%;
}
.price1 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

2. absolute dots + white background

```
<div class=item2>
  <span class=text2>
    <span class=bg2>
      Text
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class=price2>
    <span class=bg2>
      $100
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.item2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}
.item2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px grey dotted;
}
.bg2 {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

3. dumb flexbox

```
<div class=item3>
  <span class=text3>
    Text
  </span>
  <span class=dots3></span>
  <span class=price3>
    $100
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.item3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.dots3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
  min-width: 10px;
  height: 1em;
}
```

They are all shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/rzmLg4yu/62/

Each of these techniques has its own pitfalls in my case.

1. Has dot leaders at **last** line.
2. Does not work over complex background, even with mix-blend-mode (uncomment bg line to see).
   [image]
3. Has large white gaps due to line breaks (resize to see). Switching to grid is no use.
   [image]

Is there more solutions to this case?

Comment: Is the CSS above from your project or from the CSS you found?

Comment: Its just an example to show pitfalls

Answer (score 6):

Technic 3 can be improved to get rid of the wrapping gaps:

```css
body {
  color: grey;
}

.width {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  abackground: linear-gradient(45deg, yellow, black);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
}

.item3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.dots3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
  min-width: 10px;
  height: 1em;
}

.text3 {
  padding-right: 0px;
  text-align: justify; /* <--- */
}
```

```html
<div class=width>

  <div class=item3>
    <span class=text3>
        3 Text text
      </span>
    <span class=dots3></span>
    <span class=price3>
        $100
      </span>
  </div>
  <div class=item3>
    <span class=text3>3 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</span>
    <span class=dots3></span>
    <span class=price3>
        $100
      </span>
  </div>
```

Here `text-align: justify;` will space the words evenly.

---

I think your issue with the second technic is because of white background color right? 
because of `.bg2 {background: white;...}`?

Otherwise, you should've used `mix-blend-mode: lighten;` to demonstrate the issue:

```css
body {
  color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.width {
  width: 230px;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow, black);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
}

div>div {
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.simpleDiv1 {
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

.simpleDiv2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}
```

```html
<div class=width>
  <div class=simpleDiv1>darken blend. Simple text without any styles and stuff.</div>
  <div class=simpleDiv2>lighten blend. Simple text without any styles and stuff.</div>
</div>
```

If you use darken blend then any normal text will disappear with that background, let alone dot leaders.

---

Technic two without background white:

```css
body {
  color: grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.width {
  width: 230px;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  abackground: linear-gradient(90deg, yellow, black);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
}

.item2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-color: white;
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}

.item2::before {
  content: '\00a0';
  height: calc(1em - 0.5px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class=width>

  <div class=item2>
    <span class=text2>
        2 Text text
      </span>
    <span class=price2>
        $100
      </span>
  </div>
  <div class=item2>
    <span class=text2>
        2 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
      </span>
    <span class=price2>
        $100
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here I'm using white underline, instead of whole white background, to hide dotleader. But you'll get white underline while using some blend modes.

---

Technic three can be improved if we are willing to break words while wrapping:

```css
body {
  color: grey;
}

.width {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  abackground: linear-gradient(45deg, yellow, black);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
}

.item3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.dots3 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
  min-width: 10px;
  height: 1em;
}

.text3 {
  padding-right: 0px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class=width>

  <div class=item3>
    <span class=text3>
        3 Text text
      </span>
    <span class=dots3></span>
    <span class=price3>
        $100
      </span>
  </div>
  <div class=item3>
    <span class=text3>3 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</span>
    <span class=dots3></span>
    <span class=price3>
        $100
      </span>
  </div>
```

Here instead of wrapping on word boundaries, I'm wrapping on letter boundaries using `word-break: break-all`. If your font-size is 1em, then this way the maximum gap will be less than 1em, because browser won't be able to fit a letter less than 1em space.

Comment: I tried to avoid text-align: justify because it looks poor on small screens when there 2-3 words on a line.

Comment: White underline falls into same problems background does. (But doesn't require extra inline element).

Comment: Unfortunately word-break: break-all is also not suitable for me.

Comment: Can you show how does `text-align:justify` look on mobile? May be we can play with width to remove extra gaps in between words.

Comment: @panfil Specs for feature `leader()` are work in progress https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#leaders . You might wanna raise a concern about leading after first line.

Answer (score 2):

#### Three improvements for the second technique

1. I suggest using the value `multiply` for the  `mix-blend-mode` property. In the case of dark text, it gives a sharper result even on a gradient background. Look the first demo.
2. We can simplify layout of the second technique with a help of the `::first-line` pseudo-element. It can be used with "[only a small subset of CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line#allowable_properties)", but this subset contains all background-related properties.
   I think this also gives a better result against `mix-blend-mode: darken`. Compare the second and third demo.
3. And the `gap` property helps to set the minimum gap between the text and the price.

There are three demos in the snippet below:

- First one shows `mix-blend-mode: multiply` in action.
- The other two compare the effect of `mix-blend-mode: darken` on two layouts - with an extra `bg` block and with the `::first-line` pseudo-element.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/NWapXPQ?editors=1100

```css
body {
  color: grey;
}

.width {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, yellow, black);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 200px 100%;
}

.item2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
  gap: 10px;                 /* 3) */
}

.multiply .item2 {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;  /* 1) */
}

.item2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px grey dotted;
}

.bg2 {
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}


.price4,
.text4 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.price4,
.text4::first-line {         /* 2) */
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<h4><code>mix-blend-mode: multiply;</code></h4>
<div class="width multiply">
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text2>
            <span class=bg2>
                2 Text text
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class=price2>
            <span class=bg2>
                $100
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text2>
            <span class=bg2>
                2 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class=price2>
            <span class=bg2>
                $100
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text4>
            4 Text text
        </span>
        <span class=price4>
            $100
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text4>
            4 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </span>
        <span class=price4>
            $100
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<h4><code>mix-blend-mode: darken;</code> (2nd method before 4th)</h4>
<div class="width">
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text2>
            <span class=bg2>
                2 Text text
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class=price2>
            <span class=bg2>
                $100
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text2>
            <span class=bg2>
                2 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class=price2>
            <span class=bg2>
                $100
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text4>
            4 Text text
        </span>
        <span class=price4>
            $100
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text4>
            4 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </span>
        <span class=price4>
            $100
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

<h4><code>mix-blend-mode: darken;</code> (4th method before 2nd)</h4>
<div class="width">
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text4>
            4 Text text
        </span>
        <span class=price4>
            $100
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text4>
            4 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
        </span>
        <span class=price4>
            $100
        </span>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text2>
            <span class=bg2>
                2 Text text
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class=price2>
            <span class=bg2>
                $100
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class=item2>
        <span class=text2>
            <span class=bg2>
                2 Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class=price2>
            <span class=bg2>
                $100
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `mix-blend-mode: multiply` changes text color.

Comment: @panfil Thanks for your feedback. It is important for me to understand how the solution relates to your situation. I use `mix-blend-mode: multiply`  in my projects because it increases the readability of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Even the [W3C official source](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/leaders.en.html) has some disparity. You may see inconsistent rendering or poor support for invented features (such as non-monospace/preformatted, lead zero padding, varied currency widths).

Using a shim or Web Component such as [Leader-Line](https://anseki.github.io/leader-line/) would be advisable. I would recommend you experiment with dash-animation to increase visibility on busy backgrounds (at the expense of annoying someone with a busy leader).

Answer (score 0):

You can modify technique 1 to move the dot functionality from the text to another span:

```html
<div class=item1>
  <span class=text1>
    Text
  </span>
  <span class=line1></span>
  <span class=price1>
    $100
  </span>
</div>
<div class=item1>
  <span class=text1>
    Text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </span>
   <span class=line1></span>
  <span class=price1>
    $100
  </span>
</div>
<div class=item1>
  <span class=text1>
    Text text text text text text text text text text text text
  </span>
</div>
```

```css
.item1 {
  display: flex;
}
.line1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.line1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted grey;
  width: 100%;
}
.price1 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

This works as intended:

[image: This is the output]

And a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtfndyj4/)

Comment: In this case, the layout will have to be changed when changing the text, block width or screen width.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky I'm guessing you mean when the text line overflows its space. Yep it doesn't work. It was not a mistake on my part, I misinterpreted the test case that panfil provided as 3 separate texts, not an overflowing one.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item1 {
  display: flex;
  font-size:32px;
  color:#808080;
}
.line1 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.line1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #808080;
  width: 100%;
}
.price1 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class=item1>
  <span class=text1>Text text</span>
  <span class=line1></span>
  <span class=price1>$100</span>
</div>
<div class=item1>
  <span class=text1>Text text text text text text text text text</span>
   <span class=line1></span>
  <span class=price1>$100</span>
</div>
<div class=item1>
  <span class=text1>Text text text text text text text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You just copied another answer?